# url too long when posting ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting the value of a textarea on ajax call.

If the textarea value is short the post is working fine , but when textarea is too long i get a error and when i enter the url manually i get too long error

What can i do to post a extremely long url ?

Here is example html and the ajax

```
<textarea name="MSG" id="MSG" cols="80" rows="25">posts fine</textarea>
<textarea name="MSG" id="MSG" cols="80" rows="25">this wont post if has 2048 characters or more</textarea>

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/csetup?L=43570&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=24&PRINTER=1',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data) {
        hpm_txt = $(data).find('#MSG').val();
        data = null;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://www46.myfantasyleague.com/2022/message?LEAGUE_ID=10065&NAME=message29&MSG='+hpm_txt+'',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Send query string params using  jquery  "data" parameter. Read about js FormData too

Comment: any way you can show me an example with my ajax post request on how to go this?

Comment: Does the `MSG` value have to be in the URL query string? Can you not post it in the request body instead? Any chance you could link to the API documentation?

Comment: yes MSG is part of url needed to post

Comment: thanks guys , got it figured out with data parameter

Comment: So what [you said previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313983/url-too-long-when-posting-ajax#comment129474127_73313983) about the `MSG` needing to be part of the URL was incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

adding data paramenter did the trick

```
urlGET = 'https://www46.myfantasyleague.com/2022/csetup?L=10065&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=3&PRINTER=1';
urlPOST = 'https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/message?LEAGUE_ID=54418&NAME=message22';
$.ajax({
    url: urlGET,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data) {
        hpm_txt = $(data).find('#MSG').val();
        hpm_name = $(data).find('form table.report input[name="LABEL"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: urlPOST,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            data: {
                MSG: hpm_txt,
                LABEL: hpm_name
            },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {},
            error: function (xhr) {}
        });

        data = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: great! maybe you could create a var doPost = function(data) { hpm_txt...} ;  and then  use success: doPost  .